# How to get current cell value from cell factory?

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, tablecolumn

I have `TableView` with 5 `TableColumn`. One of these columns represent color of culture on the map.

```
    colorColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<Culture>(cellData.getValue());
        });
    colorColumn
            .setCellFactory(value -> {
                CellShape<Rectangle, Culture> elem = new CellShape<Rectangle, Culture>(
                        new Rectangle(50.0, 30.0, COLOR_OF_APPROPRIATE_CULTURE));
                elem.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                return elem;
            });
```

Here `COLOR_OF_APPROPRIATE_CULTURE` - it is color that is set in `Culture` object.

```
  public class Culture
{
    private Color color;
    //setter and getter
}
```

So, how to get this color field in `CellFactory`?

Comment: What is `CellShape`? Is it a `TableCell` subclass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume, `CellShape` is a `TableCell` subclass, since the callback for `setCellFactory()` must return a `TableCell` or descendant. If so, you can get hold of the row data object via the `getTableRow()` method to `TableCell`. 
It would look like:

```
myColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Data, Fieldtype>, TableCell<Data, Fieldtype>>() {

  @Override
  public TableCell<Data, Fieldtype> call(TableColumn<Data Fieldtype> param) {
    return new TableCell<Data, Fieldtype>(){

      @Override
      protected void updateItem(Fieldtype item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty); 

        Object rowDataItem = this.getTableRow().getItem();
        // Do what with the row data what you like ...

        // ...
      }
    };
  }
});
```